# Django: How to give model "choices" a brief explanation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a choices-field in my Django model, like so:

```
INTERACTIVE_TYPES = (
    ('registration_received', 'Registration received'),
    ('registration_confirmed', 'Registration confirmed'),
)

interactive_type = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=INTERACTIVE_TYPES)
```

What I also need, is a brief explanation for the user when he selects either option. This is of course possible by storing them in the database. However, I desperately want to avoid that.

Here is code to explain what I'm trying to do. Obviously this doesn't work, but I'm not sure what's the prettiest (or least awful) way to achieve the same results.

```
INTERACTIVE_TYPES = (
    ('registration_received', 'Registration received', 'Use the string {{confirm}} to place the confirmation link and {{reject}} to place the rejection link.'),
    ('registration_confirmed', 'Registration confirmed', 'Use the string {{welcome}} to place the welcoming link.'),
)

interactive_type = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=INTERACTIVE_TYPES)
```

I'd also appreciate tips if I'm crossing the lake to get the water, so to speak.

Comment: You could consider creating a special form widget that takes care of this for you.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like overkill, though.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. You need something to take care of printing those extra messages regardless, and a widget can do that for you. You could initialise the widget with something like `explanations={'registration_received': '....'}`, and keep your model's `choices` clean that way.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to display this anyway?

Either you have the Description combined: "'Registration received (Use the string {{confirm}} to place the confirmation link and {{reject}} to place the rejection link.)" (Content of the menu)

Or you use a `help_text` "First Option does foo, Second option does bar", which will be displayed below the box.

Other ways to display your additional text aren't included in the widget as it is.